# How can I dynamically set an objects keys to a variable using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
export function getNoteKeys() {
    const notesObject = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i)
        const value = localStorage[key]
        notesObject[key] = value
    }
    store.dispatch(SetActionForNotes(_.values(notesObject).sort(function(a, b) {
        return a > b
    })))
}
```

The current output I am getting for the above code is this...

```
{0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}
```

The problem with this is that when I convert this to an array I do not have the ability to continue to uniquely identify each object after an item is removed, because the indexes of the items change if one is removed.

I want to set each key set to an id for every value retrieved.
I have unique keys already set in localstorage, and I need them to uniquely identify each note in a list. I have tried many different ways and cannot figure this out.

As an example of what I am trying to do...

```
const obj = [{id: 1, value: "a"}, {id: 2, value: "b"}...]
```

Comment: Are you trying to use dynamic object keys, or just trying to map each key-value pair from localStorage to a new object shape? Your example output `obj` doesn't match what the code is doing and isn't a valid JS object. It's unclear what you are asking for. Also, the sort function comparator should return a number value, i.e. [-1, 0, 1], not a boolean to indicate sorting order.

Comment: You are already doing it with: notesObject[key] = value

Comment: `{[{id: 1}, {value: "a"}], [{id: 2}, {value: "b"}]...}` isn't valid object syntax, are you trying to get something like `[{ id: 1, value: 'a' }, { id: 2, value: 'b' }, ...]` in an array?

Comment: @DrewReese yes that is what I am aiming for. Ill edit my question so it will be correct.

Comment: Can you include also an example localStorage value so we can see where you're starting from?

Comment: @DrewReese The values are simply user input converted to JSON.

Comment: That doesn't really help us understand what `localStorage.key(i)` is, or what a value is. Just an example input to go with the expected output. This will help us see where your code is falling short of your goal and form a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is you purpose, but this will do the transformation you want.

```
Object.keys(localStorage).reduce((acc,key)=>{
  return[...acc,{id:key,value:localStorage[key]}]
},[])
```

Comment: I am assuming ```value:asd[key]``` was added in error, your answer worked once I removed ```asd```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `localStorage` is an object (versus array), and if so you can also use `Object.entries` and map the array of key-value pairs into `[{ id: 1, value: 'a' }, { id: 2, value: 'b' }, ...]`.

```
Object.entries(localStorage).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }))
```

```js
const localStorage = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
};

const res = Object.entries(localStorage).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));

console.log(res);
```

Though since objects are just associative arrays of key-value pairs, it works with arrays as well.

```js
const localStorage = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const res = Object.entries(localStorage).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));

console.log(res);
```